# [products_products_id])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (products [categories_id,products_products_id])

Tags: spring, hibernate

i have error related to the hibernate query

Foreign key (FK_jipqfc4qahmxslbxjbln9cxpm:products [products_products_id])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (products [categories_id,products_products_id])

i dont understand why it is i try lots of time but till now problem does not solve 
Here is my oneToMany relation on categories pojo

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    private int categories_id;
    @Column
    private String categories_image;
    @Column
    private int sort_order;
    @Column
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date date_added;
    @Column
    private Date last_modified;



    @Column
    private String categories_name;

    public String getCategories_name() {
        return categories_name;
    }

    public void setCategories_name(String categories_name) {
        this.categories_name = categories_name;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="categories_description",joinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name = "categories_id",referencedColumnName="categories_id")})
    private categories_description categories_description;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="products_to_categories",joinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name = "categories_id", referencedColumnName="categories_id")})
    private Set<products_to_categories> products_to_categories;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="products",joinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name = "categories_id",referencedColumnName="categories_id")})
    private Set<products> products;
```

---

and here is my products pojo

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    private int products_id;
    @Column
    private int Category_id;
    @Column
    private int products_quantity;
    @Column
    private String products_model;
    @Column
    private String products_image;
    @Column
    private float products_price;
    @Column
    private Date products_date_added;
    @Column
    private Date products_last_modified;
    @Column
    private Date products_date_available;
    @Column
    private float products_weight;
    @Column
    private String products_status;
    @Column
    private int products_tax_class_id;
    @Column
    private int manufacturers_id;
    @Column
    private String products_type;


    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="products_id")
    private products_description products_description;


     @OneToOne
     @JoinColumn(name="products_id")
     private products_to_categories products_to_categories;
```

i want categories_id as a foregin key and also primary key inside products table 
but while excuting i got this error .

please help i really appreciated.